# Generate random time series data with trend in R

Tags: r, time-series, seq, trend

I want to generate a random time series data set which will be following a positive trend.

I used the seq() function that allows me to set a starting and an ending point to my data, and also state the length of the data set.

I want to use 5-minute intervals over one week time (this is, 2017 5-minute intervals).
The code I used:

`library(chron)`

`t1 <- chron("1/1/2010","00:00:00")`

`t2 <- chron("1/8/2010","00:00:01")`

`deltat <- times("00:05:00")`

`date <- seq(t1,t2,by=times("00:05:00"))`

`frame <- data.frame(date,wcons=seq(10,100,length.out=2017))`

However, I would like to get a "smoother" trend than that. This creates a data set increasing by 90/2017 during the week. I have checked the R documentation for seq() and as far as I know, none of those functions can let me change the frequency of the increase. Which function could me helpful in my case?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is the code you provided how you generate the _random time series data_, or is this just how you generate the trend? What do you mean by a _smoother_ trend?

Comment: @henrik_ibsen I create the trend using `wcons=seq(10,100,length.out=2017)`. This meant that the sequence was increasing `by=(100-10)/2017`. After playing with my code, I found out that I can use something like `wcons=seq(10,100,by=0.00005)` for example, and this solved my problem.